# javascript copy elements with events and custom variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually use custom variables for elements in javascript. something like this:

```
document.getElementById("test").myVar=function(){
    // do something
};
```

now I need to copy one element (`document.getElementById("test")`) and append it somewhere. I tried to use `clone()` with jquery. something like this:

```
$("#test").clone(true,true).attr("id","test2").appendTo("#somewhere");
```

but it can't copy myVar in the new element. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why, oh why do you assign arbitrary properties to the elements ?

Since you use jQuery why not use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method ? (*although i still cannot understand why you would store a function on an element..*)

```
$('#test').data('myVar', function(){...});
```

---

A different abuse could be to bind a custom event handler (*[namespaced to avoid further issues](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)*), but i would stick with `.data()`

```
$('#test').bind('myVar.variables', function(){...});
```

Comment: +1 Because the second half made me laugh. (and it's the right answer)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store your additional functions:

```
$("#test").data("myVar", function(){});
```

Then when you [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) setting to `true` the argument `withDataAndEvents` it should work.

Comment: I think you should replace *could* with *should*